# Displaying Images and text in ListView for React Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to load images via a url and text using ListView and show data into List but when I populate it in a listview Image and text then my images are not show.

My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ListView, Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const styles = Style.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20
}
});

class ListViewDemo extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({
        rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(["row 1", "row 2"])
    };
}
render() {
    return (
        <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={data => {
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Image
                        source={{
                            uri:
                                "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg"
                        }}
                        style={{ width: 193, height: 110 }}
                    />
                    <Text> Asad </Text>
                </View>;
            }}
        />
    );
}
} [enter image description here][1]

export default ListViewDemo;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

The images would not render in your list view.

**Solution**

I have noticed sometimes having trouble getting images to show up when components render in react. Especially when they are loaded over a network call. I added a `style` to your `image component`, placed the `image source` into a variable and fixed some syntax errors you had in your code.

The biggest problem, and the reason it was not rendering the image was you added `{}` around your `renderRow prop` which would call for the need of a `return statement`. When you supply `()` around the `return data`, `return` is implied because your using a `fat arrow function`.

So this,

```
renderRow = { (data) => { }}
```

Became this,

```
renderRow={data => ( )}
```

**Example**

You can copy and paste this whole component into you code and it will work. 
This has been tested,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; import { ListView, Text, View, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  img: {
    width: 193,
    height: 110,
  },
});

class ListViewDemo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({ rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2 });

    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['row 1', 'row 2']),
    };
  }
  render() {
    const imageSource = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Bananavarieties.jpg';
    return (
      <ListView
        dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
        renderRow={data => (
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
              source={{ uri: imageSource }}
              style={styles.img}
            />
            <Text>{data}</Text>
          </View>)}
      />
    );
  }
}


export default ListViewDemo;
```

**Proof of Concept**

Please see the image showing your component working now,

[image]

Comment: + 1 from me nice answer but I do want to show multiple text views to the right of the screen along with the image. How to achieve that? I am a beginner in react native and I am facing too many red screens lol

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal I would love to help you buddy but you are not giving us much to go on. The easiest way is to learn to understand flex box. Try it for a while and see if you can make some tests using flex. If you can not figure it out, ask a question on here and show us some code.

Answer (score 0):

React Native provides a suite of components for presenting lists of data. Generally, you'll want to use either FlatList or SectionList first and then provide the image in the data source.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
    
    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
       flex: 1,
       paddingTop: 22
      },
      item: {
        padding: 10,
        fontSize: 18,
        height: 44,
      },
      img: {
        width: 100,
        height: 100
      },
    });
    
    const FlatListBasics = () => {
      return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <FlatList
            data={[
              {key: 'Devin', image: 'image1.png'},
              {key: 'Dan', image:'image2.png'},
          
            ]}
            renderItem={({item}) => <Image source={item.image} style={styles.img} /><Text style={styles.item}>{item.key}</Text>}
          />
        </View>
      );
    }
    
    export default FlatListBasics;
```

reference: https://reactnative.dev/docs/using-a-listview